# Disabling user interaction in a SwiftUI view without changing its appearance

Tags: ios, swiftui, fade, user-interaction, disabled-control

I have a custom view `InteractiveView` that allows user interaction. I want to show a thumbnail of that view on an overview page (inside a `NavigationLink`) so the user can tap it to navigate to the the fullscreen view.

For that reason, I need the `InteractiveView` to be non-interactive (i.e. disabled) when it's displayed as a thumbnail. I implemented this as follows:

```
NavigationLink {
    InteractiveView(viewModel)
} label: {
    InteractiveView(viewModel)
        .disabled(true)
}
```

This works as intended (i.e. tapping the view does not interact with the view but performs the navigation to the fullscreen interactive view instead).

However, the `disabled(true)` modifier also changes the `InteractiveView`'s appearance: All its subviews are faded out, i.e. their opacity is reduced and they appear semi-transparent. I understand that this is usually what I want as it signals to the user that the view is disabled and I cannot interact with it. But in my case, the user *can* interact with it as they can tap on it in order to show the fullscreen view.

### Question:

- How can I disable the `InteractiveView` while keeping its original appearance (without the fade-out effect)?
- ***Or:*** Is there a better way to disable all controls in a view without changing their appearance?

---

### Update (Additional Information)

Many answers to this question suggest using hit testing with `.allowsHitTesting(false)` instead of `.disabled(true)` in the code above. This works indeed in terms of navigation, but it violates another requirement specified in the question: namely, the "without changing its appearance" part.

#### Why hit testing doesn't work

A `NavigationLink` always changes the foreground color of its `label` view to blue, thus it modifies the `label` view's appearance. I solved this problem by using a `PlainButtonStyle` on the `NavigationLink`:

```
NavigationLink {
    InteractiveView(viewModel)
} label: {
    InteractiveView(viewModel)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // prevent change of foreground color
```

With this button style, the navigation link breaks when I add the `.allowsHitTesting(false)` modifier: The navigation link's content view doesn't intercept touches anymore, but the navigation link itself also doesn't receive (or handle) those touches. And that's the problem:

I need the correct (normal) navigation link behavior without the typical navigation link highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `allowsHitTesting` is what you may be after.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58912816/1066424

Comment: That disables the navigation link as well.

Comment: Got it. It seems like you want to just disable hit testing on the subviews of InteractiveView, as opposed to removing hit testing on the InteractiveView itself. I'm not familiar with SwiftUI, but perhaps you could create a custom function to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, for that doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried several lower levels in the view hierarchy to place the hit testing modifier. Didn't work. I updated my question to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

```
        NavigationLink {
            InteractiveView()
        } label: {
            InteractiveView()
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
```

Comment: Disabling hit testing disables the NavigationLink as well.

Comment: not if you put it on the label only, as shown

Comment: That is correct, but it has another drawback. Updated my question to explain why this solution doesn't work for me.